# Assigning additional private IP to azure vm scale set instances

Tags: python, azure, azure-vm-scale-set

Would like to know if it is possible to assign additional private ip address(secondary) to the azure instance which is part of virtual machine scale set.

For standalone azure instances, multi ip feature is available. I can easily assign additional ip via azure portal(NIC >> IP configuration) or by using azure python SDK.

Can anyone answer if it is possible to do the same thing right now to instance that is part of a vmss?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is in preview right now, you can register and learn about this feature [here](https://github.com/gbowerman/azure-myriad/tree/master/preview/network).